# Unexpected recursive dns resolution by Network Solutions

Tags: dns

I recently made www.giagni.com a CNAME to giagni.wpengine.com using Network Solutions' DNS editor. Per an email from WPEngine, giagni.wpengine.com should resolve to 104.198.107.102, and for me it does.

```
$ dig giagni.wpengine.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
giagni.wpengine.com.    120     IN      A       104.198.107.102
[...]
```

Things look different when I check with the domain's nameserver though:

```
$ whois giagni.com
[...]
Name Server: NS17.WORLDNIC.COM
Name Server: NS18.WORLDNIC.COM
[...]

$ dig @NS17.WORLDNIC.COM www.giagni.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.giagni.com.         7200    IN      CNAME   giagni.wpengine.com.
giagni.wpengine.com.    3600    IN      A       141.8.225.31
[...]
```

I can see the CNAME I created, so that's good, but where is this 141.8.225.31 address coming from?

Locally it looks like everything is fine:

```
$ dig www.giagni.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.giagni.com.         5904    IN      CNAME   giagni.wpengine.com.
giagni.wpengine.com.    1       IN      A       104.198.107.102
[...]
```

I just don't understand why NS17.WORLDNIC.COM is resolving giagni.wpengine.com differently.

Comment: Your `whois` command is returning wrong name servers.

Comment: I double-checked with a whois website. I don't see why you'd say they're wrong. What do you get?

Comment: indeed, I did not read carefully enough

Comment: But the those nameservers are definitely misbehaving, they will give that same answer to any [random query](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/giagni.wpengdneeeeeeeee.com@NS18.WORLDNIC.COM) they are not authoritative for (and seems like it has happened [before](https://blog.dotcom-monitor.com/network-services-monitoring/network-solutions-name-servers-currently-experiencing-dns-issues/))